# How do I identify Keras version which is merged to Tensorflow current?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to use Keras/TensorFlow. But some options are not supported (ex. TensorBoard embeddings_freq) . I want to know TensorFlow merging policy for Keras, especially for synchronizing schedule and how to check Keras merged version.

Answer (score 1):

The Keras in tf.keras is a reimplementation of keras and not a merge of a particular version. File issues if features you need are missing.